# Tools for sending email

Tags: email, eml

I am working on one product which requires extensive testing of emails.
I have a set of eml files (test samples) to be sent to the product in bulk.

Can anybody suggest some tool which takes these eml files as input and send out the emails to the given recipients. It can take SMTP address as input.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

for scripting smtp tests I use [swaks](http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/)

in your case that would be something like

```
swaks -f sender@example.com -t recipient@example.net -d /path/to/emlfile
```